# Need to understand broadleaf commerce custom annotation implementation

Tags: java, annotations, broadleaf-commerce

I have been trying go through code of Broadleaf Commerce. There were multiple Custom Annotations used however I was not able to locate there Processor. Can anyone help me here. To take example @AdminPresentation it a custom annotation in package org.broadleafcommerce.common.presentation;

However how this is processed throughout the app, I was not able to locate. What I have understood till now we can use Reflection or AOP for its processing. But There was nothing for this.

Please help.

Source code - https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce

Answer (score 3):

For a short answer, `org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.dao.provider.metadata.BasicFieldMetadataProvider#addMetadata` is one place that processes those annotations.

On a broader level, the controllers in the openadmin will use the AdminEntityService to get ClassMetaData (all data about how a class should be displayed to an admin user). The `@AdminPresentation` annotation is one source of this data. The method `AdminEntityServiceImpl#getClassMetadata` is the main gateway for getting the ClassMetaData.

`#getClassMetadata` calls `#inspect` and eventually gets to `PersistenceManager#inspect`. This method uses the DynamicEntityDao to eventually get to `Metadata#getFieldMetadataForTargetClass`. That method gets each field of a class via reflection, and then each of those Fields is processed through the available FieldMetadataProviders. The FieldMetadataProviders turn a `java.lang.reflect.Field` into `org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.dto.FieldMetadata`.

Any provided FieldMetadataProvider can contribute field metadata. This metadata is used in the FormBuilderService to construct the admin page.

Class References:

AdminEntityService - `org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.service.AdminEntityServiceImpl`

PersistenceManager - `org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.service.persistence.PersistenceManagerImpl#inspect`

DynamicEntityDao - `org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.dao.DynamicEntityDaoImpl#getPropertiesForEntityClass`

Metadata - `org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.dao.Metadata#getFieldMetadataForTargetClass`

FieldMetadataProvider - `org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.dao.provider.metadata.FieldMetadataProvider`, `org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.server.dao.DynamicEntityDaoImpl#fieldMetadataProviders`

FormBuilderService - `org.broadleafcommerce.openadmin.web.service.FormBuilderServiceImpl`

Answer (score -1):

Have a look to :

https://www.baeldung.com/java-custom-annotation

You will get explanations about : "default" in the Custom Annotations.

Florent COUDERT.

Comment: I am not looking for generic answers and I am well aware of how annotations are used. I am talking wrt a source code mentioned.

Comment: See Java Reflection Application Programming Interface.